# side page scrolling in iOS like on the Stocks app

Tags: ios, iphone

The standard iOS stocks app has a horizontal side scroll view. I need to replicate it for an app and for some stupid reason I cant find whats its called.

Hoping someone can help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called [uipageviewcontroller](/questions/tagged/uipageviewcontroller).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a UIPageViewController to replicate it. There are a bunch of open source project using that controller like this [one](https://github.com/an0/WLPageViewController).